# Wordpress 'custom post type' set parent page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type, it's actually already set up in the *HTML5 BLank* theme I use. I can create 'default' posts and also a "HTML5 Blank Custom Post" and both will be create posts on different pages.

I created a "Blog" page which I set to pull in my default posts. My question is how do I set a similar parent page for my custom posts? Basically I want a "Case Studies" page, which is where the custom posts will be displayed. Is it possible to set this someone in the CMS or is it something you need to hardcode?

I can see the posts display on a `www.url.com/html5-blank/new-post` page. So they will index. I just don't have a clue how to set that up as a 'page'.

Can someone shed some light on this? It feels like it should be an easy thing to do but I have a feeling it's more complicated than it should be?

Thanks in advance!